# PHP SoapClient unable to access webservice over HTTPS when using proxy

Tags: php, soap, https, proxy, wsdl

Using `SoapClient` in PHP (version 5.3.10) I've come across a problem I have not been able to find a solution to.

The combination of HTTPS and Proxy for contacting the webservice is giving me some real pain. Is there a way to get this working?

Given the following setup:

```
$WSDL = 'https://(...).php?wsdl';

$params =  array(
    'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
    'proxy_port' => 3128
);
```

This works:

```
$client = new SoapClient($WSDL);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($client->__call('someFunc', array()));
```

This gives error at some point:

```
$client = new SoapClient($WSDL, $params);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($client->__call('someFunc', array()));
```

I've tried a few twists and hacks trying to narrow the problems:

- When `$WSDL` is set to an HTTP-based service, both methods works.
- When the WSDL of a HTTPS-based service is downloaded locally and `$WSDL` is set to this, the failing method produces the functions, but fails when trying to call the function.

From initializing a client with HTTPS-url to the wsdl and proxy enabled, PHP exits with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception:
 [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://(...).php?wsdl' :
  failed to load external entity https://(...).php?wsdl
```

When initializing the client using a locally stored WSDL-definition file, PHP exits with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception:
 [HTTP] Bad Request in test.php:19
 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest
```

From my perspective this looks lika a PHP bug, but hopefully there is a way around it.
Do I have to go to libraries such as NuSoap?
Is this fixed in another version of PHP?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when using Fiddler2 proxy on localhost. Had to export Fiddler's root certificate and explicitly set `cafile` option like this

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, [
        'proxy_host' => 'localhost', 
        'proxy_port' => 8888,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create([ 
            'ssl' => [ 'cafile' => 'C:\path\to\FiddlerRoot.pem' ] ])
        ]);
```

... for the https access to service to be captured.

`FiddlerRoot.pem` is exported using `certmgr.msc` of `DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot-CE` entry in `Personal` store with `Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)` option.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a local copy of the wsdl file and I am using this options:

```
  array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'proxy_host' => self::PROXY_HOST,
    'proxy_port' => self::PROXY_PORT,
    'proxy_login' => self::PROXY_USER,
    'proxy_password' => self::PROXY_PASS,
  )
```

Maybe the options `trace` or `cache_wsdl` will help you.

Comment: All I get, even when setting and editing the different settings are an `HTTP 400 Bad Request`. Seems like some of the HTTP-headers in the outgoing message are missing or wrong?

Comment: When using the trace option you try to compare the HTTP-call with the HTTPS-call with one of this methods: SoapClient->__getLastRequest, SoapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders, SoapClient->__getLastResponse and SoapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders to see if the headers are different.

Comment: Another idea would be to try the different options for the `ssl_method` paramter (see PHP docs).

Comment: The calls are similar for both cases when using locally loaded wsdl, where the proxyed one gives a HTTP 400 Bad Request response (no data). When loading the wsdl via the url it fails before having any knowledge of the service, so no data is availabe for `__getLastRe[quest|sponse]`

Comment: Are you able to access the https-wsdl file via `file_get_contents`? Maybe the certificate is not available...

Comment: Then this creates a new problem of xsd with relative paths not working behind the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm behind a firewall. I had to set the proxy and port in order to make my code work.

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => 1,
        "proxy_host" => "PROXY_HOST_STRING",
        "proxy_port" => PROXY_PORT_NUMBER
    ]);
```